# How to make onClick function fire on the click of an icon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm trying to set up an onClick function for a FontAwesome plus sign icon. The icon only appears next to any element that does not have children (aka in my nested menu, the elements that do not have more elements within it). When I test the `onClick` by doing, `console.log` it seems that any time I click an element in the menu, it fires either twice or four times. Does anyone know what I can do to make it only fire when the plus icon is clicked? Or why it fires any time any element is clicked? See screenshots below for more details.

```
class MenuTest extends React.Component {
  state = {
    categories: [],
    objectKeys: null,
    tempKeys: []
  };
```

Here is where I have set up the `onClick`, within the FontAwesome plus sign tag.

```
  makeMenuLayer = layer => {
    const { objectKeys } = this.state;
    const layerKeys = Object.entries(layer).map(([key, value]) => {
{/*if the element still has children, insert an arrow, if not, insert nothing*/}      
var arrow = Object.keys(value).length ? (
        <FontAwesome name="angle-right" />
      ) : (
        ""
      );
{/*if the element has no children, insert a plus sign, if not, insert nothing*/}
      var ex =
        Object.keys(value).length === 0 ? <FontAwesome name="plus" onClick={console.log("clicked")} /> : "";
      return (
        <ul key={key}>
          <div onClick={() => this.handleShowMore(key)}>
            {key} {arrow} {ex}
          </div>

          {objectKeys[key] && this.makeMenuLayer(value)}
        </ul>
      );
    });
    return <div>{layerKeys}</div>;
  };

  handleShowMore = key => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      objectKeys: {
        ...prevState.objectKeys,
        [key]: !this.state.objectKeys[key]
      }
    }));
  };

  initializeTempKeys = layer => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    Object.entries(layer).map(([key, value]) => {
      const newTempKeys = this.state.tempKeys;
      newTempKeys.push(key);
      this.setState({ tempKeys: newTempKeys });
      this.initializeTempKeys(value);
    });
  };

  initializeObjectKeys = () => {
    const { tempKeys } = this.state;
    let tempObject = {};
    tempKeys.forEach(tempKey => {
      tempObject[tempKey] = true;
    });

    this.setState({ objectKeys: tempObject });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/categories").then(response => {
      this.setState({ categories: response.data });
    });
    const { categories } = this.state;
    this.initializeTempKeys(categories);
    this.initializeObjectKeys();
    this.setState({ categories });
  }

  render() {
    const { categories } = this.state;
    return <div>{this.makeMenuLayer(categories)}</div>;
  }
}
```

this is how my menu looks when some of the elements are expanded. I want the `onClick` only to fire when the plus sign next to Necktie is clicked.
[image]

This is what shows up in the console when I try to test it

[image]

The data I am working with:
[image]

Comment: Does Accessories have two children? And do Necktie also have two children?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Accessory has two children but Necktie does not. Accessory's two children are Necktie and Umbrella. I will post a screenshot of the data for a better look

Comment: I see, I think you can get around this by doing onClick={() => console.log("test")}.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo That worked! Thank you! Would you be able to explain why that works vs not using ```() =>```?

Comment: Of course, its really just a React/JSX thing! When you did     onClick={console.log("clicked")}    it will immediately execute that logic when you render your FontAwesomeIcon. To work around that, you would pass in an anonymous function instead like () => which would passively wait for your click-event-listener to trigger.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I see, I understand now. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Emily just going to post our convo here from the comments so its easier to reference the solution.

*"When you did `onClick={console.log("clicked")`} it will immediately execute that logic when you render your FontAwesomeIcon. To work around that, you would pass in an anonymous function instead `like () => yourlogic()` which would passively wait for your click-event-listener to trigger."*

```
<FontAwesome name="plus" onClick={() => console.log("clicked")} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your onclick event with a callback function and then calling console will work, as you need bind a asynchronous function with onClick rather then calling console.log directly:

```
<FontAwesome name="plus" onClick={() => {console.log("clicked")}} />
```

Thanks